# How can I save searches or browse by categorization on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

How can I effectively use Stack Overflow, being new to coding?

Is Stack Overflow designed for learning or is it more of a troubleshooting question website for people who are stuck with a bug?

I'm particularly interested in learning [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) for machine learning purposes.

Comment: Please ask _one_ question per post. _“How can I save searches”_ — by using [filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/289905). _“Is Stack Overflow designed for learning or is it more of a troubleshooting question website for people who are stuck with a bug?”_ — Ideally, neither. If you want to learn, use a tutorial, manual, or course instead. If you want to troubleshoot a bug, use all the debugging tools that are available to you. Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers; its goal is to build a library of knowledge of common problems, usable for future readers.

Comment: Give the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) a read, that will answer most if not all of the basic "what is Stack Overflow about" questions and will teach you the house rules that will keep you out of trouble. As someone new to programming, you will not be able to use Stack Overflow effectively yet. It's too soon.

Comment: The title and the body seem detached from each other (e.g., at first glance, saving searches does not seem to be related to learning Python). Presuming it is one question, can you make it more clear they are not (by [editing your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/400678/edit), not here in comments - ***without*** "Edit:", "Update", or similar)?

Comment: There are [1,520,646 Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Perhaps somebody already asked the question you wanted to ask (directly or indirectly)?

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow is not very well optimized for tutoring or coaching. It is expected you've learned to code somewhere else and then are looking for answers to a specific coding problem you face.

So you would first take a course in Python. The [Python tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) has some useful info to get you started. Once you're on track you can search / watch [Python questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=active) or try a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+machine+learning&mixed=0) or the [Filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement) (kindly provided by  [user4642212](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400678/how-can-i-save-searches-or-browse-by-categorization-on-stackoverflow#comment792117_400678))

Search does have its own help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

First of all, take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

And read everything that is in the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help

And before you ask your first question, re-read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), including everything it links to. Also following the guidance in [What is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) prevents that you post questions on the wrong site.

On Meta (the site your question is moved to now) you'll find even more guidance. I suggest to start with the FAQ posts and take it from there: [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)